# display only files starting with . (hidden)

Tags: find, ls, dot-files

I tried to display only hidden files but don't know how to do it.

That is working (but matching also dots in other places)

```
ls -la | grep '\.'
```

Was trying adding `^` but didn't find the solution.

Comment: Parsing `ls` is never a wonderful idea, but what you tried would have worked if you used the anchor `^` to denote the start of match.  `ls -la | grep '^\.'`

Comment: No it won't, the filename isn't the beginning of the line with the -l flag.  `ls -la | awk '$9 ~ /^\./'` will.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`ls -ld .*` will do what you want.

Comment: This unfortunately also shows hidden directories

Answer (score 11):

```
find . -type f -name '\.*' -print
```

Must work if you want list every hidden file down in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: `-maxdepth n` to set the depth level.

Answer (score 8):

An improvement on [Flup's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123920/26909):

```
ls -lad .[!.]* ..?*
```

This will list all files whose name starts with a dot and that are neither `.` nor `..`.

Note that if you want to pipe the output of `ls` to `grep` (which, [as pointed out by devnull](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123917/grep-display-only-files-starting-with-hidden#comment196830_123917), is never a good idea), make sure you use `\ls` or `command ls` because if `ls` is aliased to show you colored output (as it is on Debian for example), its output contains ANSI escape sequences to create colored output, which will trip up your `grep` if its pattern is anchored at the start of line.

Comment: You can use `-A` (instead of `-a`) to ignore `.`, `..`.

Comment: @OJFord+ `-A` differs from `-a` for directories that `ls` descends into, but both are (equally) ignored and useless for names specified on the command line with `-d` in effect. Also if `ls` is aliased to `--color=auto`  then piping is okay; only `--color=always` or `--color` causes trouble.

Comment: Please explain the `.[!.]* ..?*` part. Is this some kind of bash-ism?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse `ls` output, you must add `^` at beginning of regex and don't use `-l` option. Using `-l` causes each line output start with file or folder permission information, not file or folder name. So you should use like this:

```
ls -Ad | grep '^\.'
```

Or you can do with `printf` bash builtin:

```
printf "%s\n" .*
```

If you use `zsh`, you can use:

```
print -l .*
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other ways to find hidden files only.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -type f -ls
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name ".*" -type f -printf "%P \n"
```

Use `-maxdepth` to specify how far you want to search in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of val0x00ff is really good, but it forgets hidden directories.

If you want *hidden files* **and** *hidden directories*, without . and .. :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./\..+' -printf "%P\n"
```

Comment: Your suggestion fails on VMware ESXi (list no files and no directories) and sort of fails on Linux too (with maxdepth > 1, it also lists any files in a directory starting with a .), but this works on both Linux and ESXi: `find . \( -type f -o -type d \)  -name '\.*' -print`; apply `maxdepth` where needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Below one is much compact and support many variants**

1) Display hidden files, directories and sub-directories

`find .  | grep  "^\./\."`

2) Display hidden directories and sub-directories only

`find . -type d | grep  "^\./\."`

3) Display hidden files only in current and sub-directories

`find . -type f | grep  "^\./\."`

4) Display hidden files and directories in current folder

`find . -maxdepth 1 | grep  "^\./\."`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '\.*' -print
find . -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -o -type d \) -name '\.*' -print
```

Of course you can use different `maxdepth` values or remove it completely. Very helpful if you want to explore between *directories* (`-type d`) or regular *files* (`type f`) or both, and combine with other functions like:

(e.g. last modified time, based on [@piroux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14774/piroux) example - completed by [@jeroen-wiert-pluimers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/69111/jeroen-wiert-pluimers) )

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -o -type d \) -name '\.*' -exec stat -c %y {} \; -printf "%P\t"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

```
ls -a |grep -E  "^\."
```

^ indicates it's the beginning of content with regexp

Comment: A duplicate of [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123944/117549) from 3 years ago ...

Comment: I saw the previous answer , it's not duplicate , and  definitely "ls -a"  and  "ls -Ad"  don't have the same meaning .    "-a"  means list all including files/directories begins with "."    -A means list all but excluding "." , ".."  and directory content.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    ls -ap | grep -v / | grep '^\.'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, though, that the OP seems to be interested in the "long listing" format (`-l`), whereas your approach relies on the "filenames only" ouptut of `ls -a`, and is therefore likely not what the OP wants ...

Comment: This will also fail if a filename contains a newline character. it is generally a bad idea to solve this sort of thing by attempting to parse the output of `ls`.